Not getting right output from XSLT
I wrote XSLT from given XML but not getting expected output.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EPCISBody>
   <EventList>
      <ObjectEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-11T19:57:45.53Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>-08:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD7F58E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <epcList>
            <epc>438941790942</epc>
            <epc>354159881283</epc>
            <epc>571494019238</epc>
            <epc>600301574096</epc>
            <epc>738033794266</epc>
            <epc>497811017409</epc>
         </epcList>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:commissioning</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:active</disposition>
         <extension>
            <ilmd>
               <lotNumber>LOT_STM95</lotNumber>
               <itemExpirationDate>2026-02-14</itemExpirationDate>
            </ilmd>
         </extension>
      </ObjectEvent>
      <ObjectEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-11T19:57:45.53Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>-08:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8158E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <epcList>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</epc>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</epc>
         </epcList>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:commissioning</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:active</disposition>
         <extension>
            <ilmd>
               <lotNumber>LOT_STM95</lotNumber>
               <itemExpirationDate>2026-02-14</itemExpirationDate>
            </ilmd>
         </extension>
      </ObjectEvent>
      <ObjectEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-11T19:57:45.53Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>-08:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8358E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <epcList>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</epc>
         </epcList>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:commissioning</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:active</disposition>
      </ObjectEvent>
      <AggregationEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-12T14:28:45Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>+00:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8558E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</parentID>
         <childEPCs>
            <epc>354159881283</epc>
            <epc>438941790942</epc>
            <epc>571494019238</epc>
         </childEPCs>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:packing</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:in_progress</disposition>
      </AggregationEvent>
      <AggregationEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-12T14:28:45Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>+00:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8758E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</parentID>
         <childEPCs>
            <epc>497811017409</epc>
            <epc>600301574096</epc>
            <epc>738033794266</epc>
         </childEPCs>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:packing</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:in_progress</disposition>
      </AggregationEvent>
      <AggregationEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-12T14:28:46Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>+00:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8958E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <parentID>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</parentID>
         <childEPCs>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010007</epc>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.1000010008</epc>
         </childEPCs>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:packing</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:in_progress</disposition>
      </AggregationEvent>
      <ObjectEvent>
         <eventTime>2024-03-12T14:28:47Z</eventTime>
         <eventTimeZoneOffset>+00:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
         <baseExtension>
            <eventID>B88F9ACC0DD8B58E</eventID>
         </baseExtension>
         <epcList>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</epc>
            <epc>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052873</epc>
         </epcList>
         <action>OBSERVE</action>
         <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:shipping</bizStep>
         <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:in_transit</disposition>
      </ObjectEvent>
   </EventList>
</EPCISBody>

Actual--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<despatchAdvice>
   <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
         <serialShipmentContainerCode>
<serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</serialShippingContainerCode>
         </serialShipmentContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <levelId>
         <levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</levelIdentification>
      </levelId>
   </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
</despatchAdvice>

Expected--
<despatchAdvice>
  <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
 <logisticUnitIdentification>
<serialShipmentContainerCode>
  <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</serialShippingContainerCode>
</serialShipmentContainerCode>
 </logisticUnitIdentification>
 <levelId>
<levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052872</levelIdentification>
 </levelId>
  </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
  <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
 <logisticUnitIdentification>
<serialShipmentContainerCode>
  <serialShippingContainerCode>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052873</serialShippingContainerCode>
</serialShipmentContainerCode>
 </logisticUnitIdentification>
 <levelId>
<levelIdentification>urn:epc:id:sscc:0361958.0001052873</levelIdentification>
 </levelId>
  </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
</despatchAdvice>

Can someone please suggest what is missing here in XSLT code I have written. Please suggest how to achieve right output from XSLT.
XSLT used is below-
<xsl:template match="/">
  <tns:despatchAdvice>
    <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/ObjectEvent">
      <xsl:if test="contains (bizStep, 'shipping' )">
        <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
          <logisticUnitIdentification>
            <serialShipmentContainerCode>
              <serialShippingContainerCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="epcList/epc"/>
              </serialShippingContainerCode>
            </serialShipmentContainerCode>
          </logisticUnitIdentification>
          <levelId>
            <levelIdentification>
              <xsl:value-of select="epcList/epc"/>
            </levelIdentification>
          </levelId>
        </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tns:despatchAdvice>
</xsl:template>


As well as the actual and expected output please explain what you're trying to achieve

Please explain the logic of the desired transformation in words. Reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see: [mcve].

Thanks for your quick response. I have mentioned in expected output that want to achieve. Seems loop is not written properly. I tried multiple times but no luck so far. We have multiple ObjectEvent, the last Object Event in XML which has bizStep as 'shipping' has two EPCs. I am getting single EPC in output as you can see in actual result mentioned in post. Want both EPCs as shown in exptected output.

You only have one loop.

Your stylesheet refers to a root element named ns0:EPCISDocument. Your XML has EPCISBody as the root.

thats true @DJL, if condition restricting it, any idea how to iterate for another EPC as well.

@user6927606 add a second loop?

I think you want:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EPCISBody">
    <despatchAdvice>
        <xsl:for-each select="EventList/ObjectEvent[contains(bizStep, 'shipping')]/epcList/epc">
            <despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
                <logisticUnitIdentification>
                    <serialShipmentContainerCode>
                        <serialShippingContainerCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </serialShippingContainerCode>
                    </serialShipmentContainerCode>
                </logisticUnitIdentification>
                <levelId>
                    <levelIdentification>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </levelIdentification>
                </levelId>
            </despatchAdviceLogisticUnitLineItem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </despatchAdvice>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


thanks much, suggested XSLT code worked for me. I removed if condition and used suggested loop as mentioned.
